# Perform validation before every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on this component and I want to validate its fields before every render. If they are not valid I want to disable a button in the parent.

Here is what I've got thus far:

```
export default function Input(props) {

  const [inputs] = useState(props.inputs);

  const didChangeRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!_.isEqual(didMountRef.current, props.inputs)) {
      validateInput(input);
      didChangeRef.current = props.inputs;
    }
  });

  const validateInput = input => {
     const errors = useValidation(input);
     if(Object.keys(errors).length !== 0) {
       props.setIsValid(false);
     }
  }

 return (
  <input
   onChange={e=> props.setProperty(e)}>
  </input>
  <input
   onChange={e=> props.setProperty(e)}>
  </input>
 )
}
```

If an input is changed, it sets a property in the parent and this component is re-rendered. Inputs is an array of objects and I wish to validate it's contents on each render (or componentDidMount). I either manage to get it to loop infinitely or run the validation only once.

I appreciate your help.

P.S.:

I tried another approach as well, but it still ends up looping infinately:

```
export default function Input(props) {

  const didMountRef = useRef(true);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (didMountRef.current) {
      didMountRef.current = false;
      return;
    }
    validate(input);
  });

  const validate = input => {
    // validation...
  }

}
```

Here is the parent component:

```
class CreateShoppingItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      storage: {},
      isValid: true,
    };
  }

  setIsValid = (isValid) => {
    this.setState({ isValid });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Input setIsValid={this.setIsValid} inputs={this.storage.inputs} />
        <Button disable={!isValid}></Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you tell me which library is the one with `!_.isEqual`? I'd like to know what its comparison. Moreover, when you call `props.setProperty`, I guess you update the state in the parent component (the same value that you pass to `Input` as `props.inputs`. If my guess are right, I understand why you end up into a loop, but first let me know what I asked

Comment: Hello. I'm using lodash for the comparison. Sorry I missed to mention that. And yes, `setProperty` is updating the state of the parent. I also did not mention that inputs is an array of objects.

Comment: Ok then, in the `useEffect` you wrote `didMountRef`. Is this a typo, and you meant `didChangeRef`? (Just trying to pick all the pieces before try to give you an answer).
Anyways, in the `useEffect`, before the `if` statement, can you `console.log` both `didChangeRef.current` and `props.inputs`? Last question: the infinite loop happens only when you have an error, or also when you don't have any?

Comment: Yes, it was more of a typo. The console.log shows that they are always the same. The loop happens if no error is present. Essentially the ref is also updated with the current value. :(

Comment: Again, can you post also the parent component? Then I can make some try on a react environment.

Comment: I've updated the description with the parent component.

Comment: Mmmh, I'm more than willing to help you, but I need some more efforts from your side :' ) The parent component doesn't even have the implementation of `setProperty`, which could be the core of the problem. Can you create a snippet (here, for example -> https://codesandbox.io/) and post it?

Comment: Here it is - https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-shtern-p6njn Before i tried to shorten it a little, to make it easier to understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210382/discussion-between-tdranv-and-jolly).